# Dual Boot: Best file system for a shared partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I made a dual boot on my laptop.

1. I backed up all my files on an external HDD, destroyed the internal hard drive's partition table by creating a new one from an Ubuntu live USB,
2. Partitionned as following:

Windows (10) partition (150 GB) formatted as NTFS
Ubuntu (18.04.1) partition (150 GB as well) formatted as Ext4
DATA partition (1.5 TB) formatted as NTFS for now, looking for a better choice

3. Installed Windows 10 - I had to delete the Windows partition in the Windows installer, then it created all it needed by selecting the empty space.
4. Installed Ubuntu - Only customized the root mount point and GRUB location (on the Ext4 partition)

Now I'm looking to mount my data partition in both Windows and Ubuntu automatically at startup. I, of course, have disabled fast boot in Windows. I have no idea how to achieve this in Ubuntu (I already know how to assign a folder to a specific location on the hard drive in Windows).

Ideally I'd use ExFAT but I'm not sure Linux can read/write on it.

EDIT: Here's the output of sudo parted -l:

Model: ATA ST2000LX001-1RG1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda : 2000GB
Sector Size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition table : gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size  File System  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB   523MB   ntfs                 Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB   105MB   fat32                EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB   16,8MB                       Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   165GB   164GB   ntfs                 Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      165GB   329GB   165GB   ext4
 6      329GB   2000GB  1671GB  ntfs                 Basic data partition          msftdata

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I forgot basic politeness and didn't greet you guys and this is my first post and I can't see an "edit" feature.

Comment: (1) Below the question there are "share", "**edit**", "flag"... (2) no need for greetings, a Q&A site works best without them ;) (3) NTFS is fine for a shared data partition and in Ubuntu there are several methods to mount it automatically on boot. There's no point in using exFAT.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! First of all, don't worry, in fact we _prefer_ to avoid greetings (and often edit them out) here since we like to keep things simple and avoid "chit chat". That said, the [edit] button is just under your question's tags, next to "share".

Comment: Now, please [edit] your question and show us the output of running `sudo parted -l` which will list your disks and tell us which one of those you want to have available. Also, please explain what you mean by "better option" than NTFS. What's wrong with NTFS? You don't want exFAT for a non-flash drive.

Comment: @karel the answers there don't address how to automatically mount the drive on boot.

Comment: Thanks everyone. terdon I added the output of the command you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use exFAT on Linux after installing the *exfat-fuse exfat-utils* packages from aptitude on Ubuntu. I would recommend you stick to NTFS though. exFAT was designed for smaller drives.

Comment: You may add ups and down for NTFS. I also like to use NTFS for a shared partition but it's not able to keep permissions.

Comment: I thought exFAT was "more dual boot friendly", hence why I was hesitating.