# How can I install Ubuntu on an empty partition alongside Windows 10 with the ability to access another drive from both?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a 128 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD. I made two partitions on the SSD, one containing Windows 10 (pre-installed) and other empty. I want to install Ubuntu on the empty partition of the SSD.

If I do that, will I be able to access the HDD from either of the OSs? If so, how can I do it? Please explain in detail...

I need both OSes because I want Windows 10 for gaming and Ubuntu for programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows) and [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As a general rule, do a quick search to see if your question has been asked before posting a new one. In this case, yYou have posted a question that has been asked many times, see if this one helps you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086723/dual-boot-best-file-system-for-a-shared-partition

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand it. I am not so good with all the technical words,can someone please explain it to me on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

yes you can install ubuntu from another partition together with windows in ssd drive.

you can access partition on hdd in windows or linux ..

but i suggest to turn off fasboot mode in advanced power options(windows). becouse some time if you try bootup to linux. you can see file/folder on hdd . but you can't write, edit or delete it.

or

you can change filesystem on hdd partition to "exfat" and install "extfat-utils" to support mount hdd in linux.. if you want fastboot active and write to hdd drive in linux.

Comment: If i change hdd partition to exfat( i am assuming u mean FAT32) ...then can i access that partition from windows. If so , then you mean to say that ubuntu cant access ntfs? And windows can access both ntfs and fat? Correct? Thanks for the help..

Comment: ubuntu can read ntfs system files. but the "fast boot" feature in Windows, creates problems with the ntfs file system on Ubuntu "if" windows fastboot activated. the solution I mentioned before, is that there are 2 choices:
1. Disable Windows FastBoot (the fastest way)
2. changing the filesystem to "exfat" can make the partition writable in ubuntu and fastboot windows still active.